# Meta tag is showing description on page content

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

i'm using this `meta` tag to show description on facebook when user share the news. I'm using ShareThis to share the news...

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<%=RSnoti("Titulo")%>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://alsite.com.br/robertoengler/<%=replace(RSnoti("foto"),"../","")%>"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<%=RSnoti("texto")%>"/>
```

As you can see here: http://alsite.com.br/robertoengler/noticia2.asp?id=1.

I'm usign ASP Classic to call the Title, Image and Description, but only description is showing above the content page

How i can fix that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
<meta property="og:title" content='<%=RSnoti("Titulo")%>'/>
<meta property="og:image" content='http://alsite.com.br/robertoengler/<%=replace(RSnoti("foto"),"../","")%>'/>
<meta property="og:description" content='<%=RSnoti("texto")%>'/>
```

Comment: That only works because the description text just happens to have no single quotes in it. If it would, this solution would have the same problems!

Comment: nice.. i change the quotes, and this works fine... thank you...!

Answer (score 0):

The content of the `content` contains HTML markup. It should contain only plain text. So the first quote in the content fouls up your page.

So you should sanitise what goes in there. Either remove all HTML markup, or change things like quotes into entity references like `&quot;`.